# Went through, Been through and Gone through usage

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What are the differences between **went through**, **been through** and **gone through**.

For instance:

- I have BEEN THROUGH a lot this year.
- I WENT THROUGH a lot this year.
- I have GONE THROUGH a lot this year.

Comment: In your exact context it's entirely a stylistic choice whether you've ***been*** or ***gone** through* [some taxing experiences], where I personally can't see even a *nuance* of difference in meaning. The alternative ***went** through* is again a stylistic choice - but unlike the other two "Perfect" constructions, Simple Past doesn't imply any particularly strong connection between the past activity and the speaker's ***current*** circumstances (so #1 and #3 might be used as "excuses / explanations" for something current, where #2 simply tells us about the past).

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes!!! thank you so much.